# Easy way to scale image based on other image's scalesize?

Tags: android, view, scale

I have a layout with an imageview that almost entirely fills the view. It has a gap in the middle where a button is positioned. When there is no stretching this fits exactly into eachother. Because the button has different drawables for different states, it needs to be decoupled from the rest of the graphics.

However, when the size of the phone is too small, the background image will scale, but the centered image ofcourse not. This leads to it being out of proportion, and taking up more space than needed.

Is it somehow possible to scale an imageview based on the scale of another imageview?
Or is there another way to make this work? (I am thinking about making the button image as large as the other background image with transparant space around it, so it auto shrinks as much).

Answer (score 0):

You should use scaling factor for each screen density.

Maybe that can help and explain how to solve the problem http://dexxtr.com/post/50327457086/multiple-screens-and-scaling-android-ui-images